# Opening files in Nautilus with the Space key, how to disable?

Tags: nautilus, shortcut-keys

Is there a way to prevent Nautilus from opening a file or entering a directory when pressing the <kbd>Space</kbd> key? I would like to disable this behavior. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, **no** it isn't possible to disable this shortcut. This is unlikely to change, see [bug 606403](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=606403).

A way around this would be to use [Nautilus-Elementary](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/09/nautilus-elementary-ppa-now-working-for-maverick-users/) which doesn't use <kbd>Space</kbd> by default.

Comment: Thanks, I gave it a try and Nautilus-Elementary has this shortcut disabled.