# In Nautilus' "Save As ... " dialog, how can I open a (sub-)folder using my keyboard (rather than the mouse)?

Tags: nautilus, shortcut-keys

a case of ... title says it all ?

- In `Nautilus`' "**Save As ...** " dialog, how can I **open** a *sub*-**folder** using my **keyboard** (rather than the <strike>mouse</strike>) ?

thx !

Comment: My usual method would start with `Alt R` (cf http://askubuntu.com/questions/269637/in-a-save-as-dialog-whats-the-quickest-way-to-keyboard-navigate-to-rec), then using `down-arrow` to select a folder (or use `Alt up` to escalate a directory)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to navigate through directories via the Gtk Save as dialogue. This is not possible by pressing [Enter], as it saves the file in the current directory.

Instead, use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, after focusing on the correct part of the dialogue using the [TAB] key, and finding your desired folder using the arrow keys.

Comment: See https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=606403 and http://askubuntu.com/questions/27623/opening-files-in-nautilus-with-the-space-key-how-to-disable

Answer (score 1):

You can enter the subfolder name in the **Name** field and use <kbd>Tab</kbd> for autocomplete.

[image: Enter subfolder name in the Name field]

Or if you don’t know the subfolder names, you can use <kbd>↓</kbd> and <kbd>↑</kbd> arrow keys to put the focus **out of** Name field. Then you can use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to focus on folder field, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open a folder.

[image: Put focus on folders]

Comment: Though feasible, it's feels a lot more goofy n clumsy than in the terminal; doesn't seem to outperform reaching for the mouse (or using the TrackPoint)...